# Setting up data source for Sections in UITableView Based off of Data from Backend

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm learning how to utilize table views & table view cells and today I wanted to practice using sections within table views. Setting the section title and sorting the data into those specific sections is fairly easy, especially when using enums.

To make it a bit more of a challenge, I wanted to see how difficult it would be to have the section titles based off of Team Names stored on Firebase and have the rows consist of users that are apart of that specific team. I've come to realize that this is extremely difficult for someone that's still learning Swift.

Heres how the structure looks on firebase:

[image]

The users have the ability to create their own team names & these team names will serve as the titles. So what I've done is created an array of strings, observed the team names and added them to the array. From there, I set the titles of the sections to each team name. **The problem Im having is putting the correct users under each team.**

If there were 40 teams, I could easily create 40 sections with the correct titles, but I can't seem to figure out how to sort each user into the correct section.

Comment: Can you show structure for both Teams and Players Collection from firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a simple implementation of your problem. You have a player class which is your Firebase data.

```
class Player {
    var name: String
    var teamName: String

    init(name: String, teamName: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.teamName = teamName
    }
}
```

Create a `Team` class to store your section data.

```
class Team {
    var teamName: String
    var players: [Player]

    init(teamName: String, players: [Player]) {
        self.teamName = teamName
        self.players = players
    }
}
```

Store all the players in an array `players` after you get the data from Firebase. Now you can have a method which returns an array which contains `Team` objects which has `teamName` and `players` which is an array containing the filtered players of the sharing the same `teamName`

```
func getTeams() -> [Team] {
    var teams: [Team] = []
    while !players.isEmpty {
        guard let referencePlayer = players.first else {
            print("All players sorted.")
            return []
        }
        let filteredPlayers = players.filter { (player) -> Bool in
            return player.teamName == referencePlayer.teamName
        }
        players.removeAll { (player) -> Bool in
            return player.teamName == referencePlayer.teamName
        }
        let team = Team(teamName: referencePlayer.teamName, players: filteredPlayers)
        teams.append(team)
    }
    return teams
}
```

Now call this method in `viewDidLoad` and reload the table.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return teams.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return teams[section].players.count
}
```

Comment: Hey so Im just now testing this out and theres a few issues. Teams is just a local variable declared in getTeams, so Im not able to display that count in numberOfSections or use it in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Its best to just declare it as a global variable. That way it will work. Can you update your answer?

Comment: And Im also getting this error: Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Bool' to expected argument type 'Bool' --> on the players.removeAll line you provided

Comment: @Vandal Do not use global variable, just have an `Team` array inside your class. Also `players` is again a `Player` array that you create while forming the data source from the API call. Since i don't have any knowledge how you do that, i just wrote it like that. Also the filter works fine for me. Please make sure there are no syntax problems in your code.

Comment: @Vandal sure mate.