# Separating objects by column in a Table View Controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase

I have a user object that takes in a few fields such as name, email, and an occupation field that stores a string array.

When a user is creating an account, they're prompted to enter up to 3 occupational choices, which is then stored in an array and uploaded to firebase under their user id:

[image: occupation node under a user's id]

I have a table view controller with the purpose of displaying all of the users, but separated by their occupation. The idea is to allow users to search other people based off of their particular occupation so for reference, all the designers on the app can be found on the tableview controller under the section titled "Designer". In another scenario, if the user is a Designer AND a developer, they should show up under Developer as well.

**The key part here is the fact that users enter their occupation manually**. So I can just create an array with a specific set of occupational titles. I have to get a list of all occupations, and then filter the users based off of the occupational title. Using the help I received from a smaller version of this idea ([Smaller Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845172/setting-up-data-source-for-sections-in-uitableview-based-off-of-data-from-backen/51846331?noredirect=1#comment90896607_51846331)), I came up with a function to separate users by their occupation but it's not working at all:

```
  func getOccupations() -> [IndexedOccupations] {
    while !users.isEmpty {

    //-- filter the users
        guard let referencedUser = users.first else { return [] }
        for x in (referencedUser.occupation?.count)! {
            let filteredUsers = users.filter { (user) -> Bool in
                for y in user.occupation.count {
                    return user.occupation[y] == referencedUser.occupation[x]
                }
                return false
            }

    //-- create an occupation object with an occupation name, and list of filtered users & return occupations
            let indexedOccupation = IndexedOccupations(occupation: referencedUser.occupation[x]!, users: filteredUsers)
            occupations.append(indexedOccupation)
        }}

    return occupations
}
```

Heres how both objects look for reference btw:

```
class User: NSObject {

//-- things that a User will have stored
var id: String?
var bio: String?
var city: String?
var name: String?
var email: String?
var picture: String?
var state: String?
var links: [String]?
var playerID: String?
var occupation: [String]?

    //-- initializer method
    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
        self.name = dictionary["Name"] as? String
        self.email = dictionary["Email"] as? String
        self.city = dictionary["City"] as? String
        self.state = dictionary["State"] as? String
        self.picture = dictionary["Picture"] as? String
        self.bio = dictionary["Bio"] as? String
        self.playerID = dictionary["playerID"] as? String
        self.links = dictionary["Links"] as? [String]
        self.occupation = dictionary["Occupation"] as? [String]
    }
```

}

And Occupations:

```
class IndexedOccupations: NSObject {

//-- things that a user will have stored
var occupation: String?
var users: [User]

//-- initializer method
init(occupation: String, users: [User]) {
    self.occupation = occupation
    self.users = users
}
```

}

Comment: Some thoughts. In general Array's should be avoided in NoSQL databases. You're better off creating a node of occupations the user can select from with keys created with childByAutoId. */occupations/key_0/occ: Designer* and */occupations/key_1/occ: Developer* etc. Why? Because am I a coder or  programmer or  developer? If the user enters that, it adds a lot of variables which makes it hard to group. To  separate users by occupation, load the users and their data and sort by occupation key. That will group them by occupation. Oh, load the occupations into an array so you can use them as labels.

Comment: @Jay thank you so much for that advice

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a dictonary like:

```
var userByOccupation: [String: [User]] = []
```

And then make a function where you insert all Users in this Dictonary with the Key being their Occupation (if they have more then 1 just add new Key with same Value)

So I don't know how your Data Model looks like until Occupations but what you need to do is just iterate over every child of Occupations and for every child take the value and save this value as key and the current User as Value into the userByOccupation Array.

So first get the current User and then:

```
 ref?.child("Occupation").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot{
                if let occupation = rest.key as? String{
                    //And here insert OCCUPATION/USER like
                    if (userByOccupation[occupation] != nil) {
                       userByOccupation[occupation]?.append(user)
                    } else {
                       userByOccupation[occupation] = [user]
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

EDIT to comment-question:

I don't know if it is the best solution but here's how I'd do it.
After loading the dictionary just make an array of all keys like this

```
allOccupations = Array(userByOccupation.keys)
```

After this you can order this array for example -> dictionaries are unordered!

And then:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return allOccupations.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return allOccupations[section]
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userByOccupation[allOccupations[section]].count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Then get the user like this
   guard let allUsers = userByOccupation[allOccupations[section]] else {
   return }
   let currentUser = allUsers[indexPath.row]
}
```

Made this pretty fast so I'm sorry if there are errors in it, I hope it helps you!

Comment: Hey I haven't tried this out yet but based off of your logic, it makes completely sense and pushed me into the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: So this works. Thanks again, but im having trouble populating this data into a tableview. I want to use the occupation title as the section and the users will fill in each row depending on the section. Any references on how to use dictionaries with table views?

Comment: Added something I hope this helps