# Swift sorting tableview into separate sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sections

I've written a program where a user can take pictures and track information about their miniature collections and everything works as intended. Now I'm looking to add some different functionality for the tableview, and I'm not quite sure what would be the best way to go about it. At present when the user adds a model, it appends to a single dictionary of dictionaries then displays it in the tableview in the order it was appended. I would like to sort or separate the data into separate sections based on what codex the model is from.

Whether it would be better to generate separate sections programmatically or use an index, I'm not sure. But in either case, I am at a complete loss of how to accomplish this.

Here is the tableview code I currently have, in case it helps

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return models.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Dequeue reusable Cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "modelCell", for: indexPath) as! modelCellTableViewCell
    // Fetch Item
    let model = models[indexPath.row]
    // Configure Table View Cell
    cell.modelNickname?.text = model.modelNickname
    cell.modelNickname.textColor = UIColor(red:0.24, green:0.31, blue:0.35, alpha:1.0)
    cell.modelName?.text = model.modelName
    cell.codexName?.text = model.codexName
    cell.modelOption1?.text = model.modelOption1
    cell.modelOption2?.text = model.modelOption2
    cell.modelOption3?.text = model.modelOption3
    cell.modelOption4?.text = model.modelOption4
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let imageName = model.codexName + model.modelName + model.modelOption1
    let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(imageName)
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePath){
        cell.modelImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)

    }else{
        print("No Image found")
    }
    return cell
}
```

Any help/suggestions you could offer would be a big help.

Comment: This should help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846331/7734643

Comment: @RakeshaShastri the idea of using a second class is an interesting one that I will have to play with. Unfortunately the code you provided in your link doesn't seem to be working for me. Thank you all the same

Comment: What issues are you facing?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I am trying to figure out what to place into cellForRowAt so that everything works. At present Im getting an Index out of range alarm